# Download a Facebook Video (.mp4) via PHP

Tags: php, facebook, video, download

So for example I have this URL:

```
http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/hvideo-ak-prn2/v/1032822_578813298845318_1606611618_n.mp4?oh=c3c6a02985213f7c47386f4653792ca6&oe=5200506F&__gda__=1375798216_02752679a44bc4b3c514bee21e000959
```

How can I download the video source file via PHP?

**Note that downloading the URL will not give me the video source!**

```
// does not work:
file_put_contents('video.mp4', 'http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/hvideo-ak-prn2/v/1032822_578813298845318_1606611618_n.mp4?oh=c3c6a02985213f7c47386f4653792ca6&oe=5200506F&__gda__=1375798216_02752679a44bc4b3c514bee21e000959');      
// this does not download the video source but instead gets me a file that links to the video hosted on Facebook.
```

Comment: you have to file_get_contents($url) before putting the contents

Comment: Funny video by the way ;) Upvotes for the video :)

Comment: how to find the URL of the video through iD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file_put_contents('derp.mp4', file_get_contents('http://video.ak.fbcdn.net/hvideo-ak-prn2/v/1032822_578813298845318_1606611618_n.mp4?oh=c3c6a02985213f7c47386f4653792ca6&oe=5200506F&__gda__=1375798216_02752679a44bc4b3c514bee21e000959'));`

Comment: how to use this code for downloading video of facebook?

Comment: This script downloads the file to my FTP. But how to make a file download to a computer?

Comment: check this tool and let know if i can paste the script here https://infoconic.com/tools/facebook-video-downloader-direct-download-fb-video/

Answer (score 1):

This code is more smart, you just have to provide the video link in this code. To get the video link simple right click on video and then click **Show Video link** or you can directly copy video link from browser URL bar as shown in below image:
[image: Copy video URL]

Then paste that URL in **PASTE_FACEBBOOK_VIDEO_LINK_HERE** section of code below

```
<?php
    $options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'custom user agent string'));
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = file_get_contents('__PASTE_FACEBBOOK_VIDEO_LINK_HERE__', false, $context);
    preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', strip_tags($response), $match);
    $searchword = 'video';
    $matches = array_filter($match[0], function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });
    $filename = rand().".mp4";
    file_put_contents($filename, fopen(reset($matches), 'r'));
```

The resultant .mp4 file will look like i.e 24424353.mp4

Comment: This script downloads the file to my FTP. But how to make a file download to a computer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way of doing this. You need to create the functions for the HD and SD quality and then the file getting function which uses curl

```
function hdLink($curl_content)
{
    $regex = '/hd_src:"([^"]+)"/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $curl_content, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

function sdLink($curl_content)
{
    $regex = '/sd_src_no_ratelimit:"([^"]+)"/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $curl_content, $match1)) {
        return $match1[1];
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
function url_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

So in your HTML you will pass the Facebook video URL to the url_get_contents() function

```
<?php 
require_once("functions.php");

if (!empty($_POST["url"]) ) {

    $data = url_get_contents($_POST["url"]);
    $hdlink = hdLink($data);
    $sdlink = sdLink($data);

    if (!empty($sdlink) && !empty($hdlink) ) {?>

       <a target="_blank" download data-href="<?php echo $hdlink; ?>" href="<?php echo $hdlink; ?>" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">Download Video</a>
   <?php }

 }
 ?>
```

Reference: [How to develop your own Facebook Video Downloader in 3 Steps](https://answerbox.net/tutorials/how-to-develop-your-own-facebook-video-downloader-in-3-steps/) on [answerbox.net](https://answerbox.net)